# To extract the DateTime from the name of file(ex. "vga_20171201.txt") in U-SQL

Tags: visual-studio, u-sql

I want to extract the filename string as a DateTime column.
The code for it as follows:
@data =
    EXTRACT
        ...
        filename_date DateTime
    FROM    "/input/vga_{filename_date}.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1);

filename = vga_20171201.txt

whenever i have used datatype as string or int, it's work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify [.net date format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) along with the virtual column name to get that behaviour, like this:

```
@data =
    EXTRACT someData string,
            filename_date DateTime
    FROM "/input/vga_{filename_date:yyyy}{filename_date:MM}{filename_date:dd}.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows : 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a series of files that are named like 1601.gz to represent January of 2016.  {date:yyMM}.gz or {date:yy}{date:MM}.gz don't seem to

Comment: Hi Chris - could you please add this as a new question and I will look at it for you.

Comment: Hi @ChrisMitchell, I’ve worked up an answer for this question.  If you post your question as a separate question I will answer it.