# U-SQL Azure Data Lake Analytics search files by date

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I have U-SQL script that uses file pattern to find files in Azure Data Lake and extracts some data from them:

```
DECLARE @input_file string = @"\data\{*}\{*}\{*}.avro";
@data = EXTRACT 
        Column1 string,
        Column2 double
FROM @input_file
USING new MyExtractors.AvroExtractor();
```

File pattern is:

```
data/{Namespace}-{EventHub}-{PartitionId}/{Year}-{Month}-{Day}/{Hour}-{Minute}-{Second}
```

**Problem**: Custom extractor is executing very slow. I have many files in the Data Lake and it takes 15hrs to process and costs $600USD per run. Too slow and too expensive.

I only need to extract fresh data from files that are not more than 90 days old. How can I filter out old files using file pattern, file date modified or any other technique?

Comment: Hey Andrei, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345848/to-extract-the-datetime-from-the-name-of-fileex-vga-20171201-txt-in-u-sql/50350399#50350399) for how to work folder names with a date structure into a virtual column.  Let me know if you need me to work up an example.

Comment: @wBob ty. I did see this. The problem is, I'll have filename *after* the extraction step. My problem is the extraction, I want to optimize fileset before the processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage GetMetadata activity in Azure data factory to retrieve lastModifiedTime of the files.

ref doc:
[Get metadata activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity)

And there's a relevant post about incremental copy:

[Azure data factory | incremental data load from SFTP to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298122/azure-data-factory-incremental-data-load-from-sftp-to-blob)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.AddDays` method of `DateTime.Now`, although whether or not this actually filters out all your files is (I think) dependent on your custom extractor, eg

```
//DECLARE @input_file string = @"\data\{*}\{*}\{*}.csv";
DECLARE @input_file string = @"\data\{Namespace}-{EventHub}-{PartitionId}\{xdate:yyyy}-{xdate:MM}-{xdate:dd}\{Hour}-{Minute}-{Second}.csv";


// data/{Namespace}-{EventHub}-{PartitionId}/{Year}-{Month}-{Day}/{Hour}-{Minute}-{Second}
@input =
    EXTRACT Column1 string,
            Column2 double,
            xdate DateTime,
            Namespace string,
            EventHub string,
            PartitionId string,
            Hour int,
            Minute int,
            Second int
    FROM @input_file
    USING Extractors.Csv();
//USING new MyExtractors.AvroExtractor();


@output =
    SELECT Column1,
           Column2
    FROM @input
    WHERE xdate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90);


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

In my simple tests with .Csv this worked to reduce the input stream from 4 to 3 streams, but as mentioned I'm not sure if this will work with your custom extractor.

[image: Local results]